# AWS SQS multiple DLQs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

we have currently a sqs queue for processing incoming data. Is there a recommended way for managing two DLQs for one queue?

- if there is a parsing error of the incoming data, then I want to move the message directly into a "userInput" DLQ, without redrives
- if our mongo is on maxConnections, or any other error occurs, then the configured redrive policy should take place

Do I have to put the message manually into the dlq for the first szenario, or is there a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: I will use [deleteMessage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SQS.html#deleteMessage-property) and [addMessage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SQS.html#sendMessage-property) in the lambda and manage the logic myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Amazon SQS queue **only has one Dead Letter Queue**.

If a message is read from an SQS queue more than a defined number of times, the message can be moved to the Dead Letter Queue for later processing. However, there is no control over what conditions will send the message to the Dead Letter Queue. It is simply based on a message being retrieved more than the `maxReceiveCount`.

See: [Amazon SQS dead-letter queues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-dead-letter-queues.html)

Please note that SQS itself does not process the message. Rather, you will have an app or an AWS Lambda function that reads the message from the queue and processes the message. Therefore, you could program your desired functionality (checking incoming data, responding to Mongo maxConnections) into the code that is processing the message from SQS. If it detects such a problem, that program could send the message to a specific queue, and then delete the original message from the source SQS queue.

This would have the same behaviour as having "multiple DLQs", except that *your code* is responsible for the logic of moving the messages to these queues, rather than Amazon SQS doing it.

Comment: Thank you for the help! But I have one more question. What happens if I delete the message manuelly from the original queue, but also let the lambda throw an error. For better statistics in cloudwatch. Gets the message added again to the queue by some aws magic?

Comment: It would be difficult to manually delete a message, since Lambda will be 'grabbing' it very quickly from the queue. If it fails to process correctly, then Lambda will attempt to re-process the message. I do not recommend trying to 'cheat' the system.

Answer (score 1):

`SQS` Supports only Single `DLQ` .

Alternatively what you could do is, Let the **Consumer** of the `**Queue**` Handle your first case. Meaning **"if there is a parsing error of the incoming data"** Let the **Consumer** Move it to another `queue`.

And The **Second case** of `redrive policy` will be handled Automatically and Moved to `Real DLQ` after the `maxReceiveCount`

Answer (score 0):

You can have only one DLQ for an queue.

[image]

However, you could subscribe a **lambda function** to that one DLQ.

The lambda function could **process the "bad" messages** and distributed to other DQLs queues. So you could have additional DLQs for which the function would filter the messages.